# What is the mathematical explanation for selecting the minimal element in the matrix row

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

What is the mathematical explanation for selecting the minimal element in the matrix row?

If I have the following matrix

> $\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  1 & 0 & 0  \\  0 & 1 & 0 \\  1 & 1 & 1 
>  \\ \end{array} \right)$

I need to select the minimal element in each row.

Then arrange the items as a set or vector

> {0,o,1}

What is the mathematical process that was based on them.

My attempts to explain this process mathematically

Assume 
matrix

> $M=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  V_1   \\  V_2  \\  V_3 
>  \\ \end{array} \right)$

Where $V_1=\{1,0,0\},V_2=\{0,1,0\}$ and $V_3=\{1,1,1\}$

> $min(M)=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  min(V_1)   \\  min(V_2)  \\  min(V_3) 
>  \\ \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  0   \\  0  \\ 1 
>  \\ \end{array} \right)$

therefore we get $min(M)$ as state vector  :

> $$V=min(M)=\{0,0,1\}$$

Is this math operation correct

Comment: AFAIK, this operation has no utility.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you mean by  no utility

Comment: Virtually no use. (Except maybe in graph theory, with $0/1$ matrices.)

Comment: It is unclear to me what is being asked here. Are you asking for example of aplications? asking for an algorithm? or something else.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh  I asking for an algorithm.

Comment: This process is in the Mathematica program `Min /@`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a classical computer and given a vector $v$, find its smallest element. To do so just do a linear scan.

Now, repeat this process for each row.

Complexity of the approach: $O(mn)$.

Comment: Can you explain the example above.

I am grateful to you for your second answer to my questions

Comment: For the first row, $[1, 0, 0]$, initialize a variable$x$  with the first element, $x = 1$. now visit the second element. If it is smaller than it, update it. second element is smaller so update it, now $x=0$. visit the next element, $0$ is not smaller. In the end $x=0$.

Repeat for other row.

Comment: If you have access to mathematica, you should used the function min, rather than write your own code.